# TFS 2018 Cancelling Visual Studio Test locks dll

Tags: visual-studio-test-runner

As part of a build definitions, we have a Visual Studio Test step. The problem is when the build is canceled manually during VS Test step, it leaves the vstest86.exe process running in the build machine which causes a new build to fail because some dll files are locked by the VS Test step from the earlier build. I have to manually kill the process by logging in to the server or using powershell but am hoping there is a better way to handle this problem. Is there a setting in the Visual Studio Test step where it terminates the process when the VS test step is canceled or halted?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio Test you are using? with Version 2.0, you could switch off "Run in isolation" this makes the process to run on Non-Isolation which make sure the process is terminated if the build is cancelled.

[image]